# Slow line of background code. How to bypass/replace/speed up. VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, optimization, unmanaged

I have been looking at the speed of my software trying to fine a line here and there that I can speed up. I do NOT need help with general optimisation. I have found a specific line of background unmanaged code that seems to be taking a very long time, even when the amount of calls are considered. This is the line:

```
system.windows.forms.unsafenativemethods.getwindowtext(handleRef hWnd, StringBuilder lpstring, int nMaxCount)
```

Does anyone know:

> 1. how to speed it up/bypass it if it's not useful/replace it with
>      something better.
> 2. specifically where I would have written something in my code that causes this to be called - the more example the better on this one!
>      I've found some related topics on Google. But each of these relate to
>      a specific issue such as an error occurring when a one thread asks
>      another thread for something and the other thread has become detached.
>      [This Link](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/sasha/archive/2010/10/03/the-case-of-the-wrong-window-owner.aspx) is helpful, but I can't quiet get my head around it.
>      Any and all help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It's very hard to help you without any idea of what your program is doing. I assume it's a WinForms app - but what's it doing? I'd expect a profiler to highlight what's calling the troublesome function.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. My program is running a set of simulations. Mostly maths based. I do keep the form updated and all the processing goes on in async threads so the form doens't lock up.

Comment: How often are you using the `Text` property of controls/windows? My simple guess is that that's what's calling GetWindowText...

Comment: It does seem to be this. I thought it must have been to complicated for that to be the answer but you're correct. If you put it in an answer other than a comment I'l;l tick it as the accepted answer. Thanks again!

Comment: Done, with a suggestion to improve things :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using [`Control.Text`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.text.aspx) a lot - this seems like the most likely caller of `GetWindowText`.

If you're updating your UI with the results of your simulation every time the simulation makes progress, you may well be able to improve the performance significantly just by rate-limiting the updates (e.g. just update 5 times per second).